# Проверить коллекцию на существование только одного объекта с соответствующим значением атрибута

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть диаграмма классов

```
public class Particip
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; } = new List<Result>();
}

public class Result
{
    public int SubjectCode { get; set; } //1-русский язык, 2-математика, 3-физика
    public int Mark5 { get; set; } //отметка по 5-ти бальной шкале
}
class Program
{       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var participResults1 = new List<Result>
        {
            new Result { SubjectCode = 1, Mark5 = 2 },
            new Result { SubjectCode = 2, Mark5 = 2 },
            new Result { SubjectCode = 3, Mark5 = 3 }
        };

        var participResults2 = new List<Result>
        {
            new Result { SubjectCode = 1, Mark5 = 3 },
            new Result { SubjectCode = 2, Mark5 = 3 },
            new Result { SubjectCode = 3, Mark5 = 2 }
        };

        var particips = new List<Particip>
        {
            new Particip { Name = "Иван", Results = participResults1 },
            new Particip { Name = "Андрей", Results = participResults2 }
        };

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Тут описываются участники тестирования и их результаты по предметам.

---

### Вопрос

1. Необходимо узнать: есть ли в коллекции `particips` учаcтники у которых
   только по **одному** предмету стоит 2 (`Mark5 == 2`).
2. И изменить эту цифру на 3.

Т.е. в данном примере это участник Андрей - у него **только одна** двойка (по физике) и надо обновить коллекцию `particips` с правкой этой двойки на три.

---

### Попытки

*клянусь* Я перепробовал различные варианты методов `Any`, `Where` и `Count` и ничего не вышло. Не пробовал `GroupBy` - из-за вложенности коллекции я не знал с какого "боку" подойти.

Comment: [MSDN: Enumerable.Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx). Хотя нет :-) вопрос не соответствует заголовку. А хотя нет - походит

Comment: _клянусь Я перепробовал различные варианты методов_ - добавляй варианты(код) которые пробовал, с описанием чем именно не подходит

Comment: @Grundy _добавляй варианты(код) которые пробовал, с описанием чем именно не подходит_. Спасибо за замечание. Я это обязательно учту в своих будущих постах.

Comment: ты можешь добавить их и в этот вопрос, воспользовавшись кнопкой [edit] для редактирования

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подсказка: с Results тоже можно работать средствами LINQ.

Например, так:

```
var matched = particips
    .Where(p => p.Results
        .Where(r => r.Mark5 == 2) //Получаем список результатов, равных 2.
    .Count() == 1); //Проверяем, что для текущего элемента есть только один такой результат
```

Таким образом, мы имеем искомый список двоечников, которых можно простить.

Процедура прощения двоечников будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
foreach (var item in matched)
{
   //Мы уже знаем, что для каждого элемента есть только один нужный результат, 
   //так что можно не париться:
   item.Results.First(r => r.Mark5 == 2).Mark5 = 3;
}
```

Comment: Можете `.First(r => r.Mark5 == 2)` добавить в конец первого LINQ

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov Ну, автор задал два вопроса, я дал два ответа. Так-то можно вообще без второго запроса, поскольку это ссылочные типы

Comment: @eastwing, каким образом без второго запроса?

Comment: @Grundy например, в первом запросе селектом собрать нужные элементы в последовательность, и дальше с ней работать уже без запроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
particips.Select(p => new { Particip = p, Mark5_2 = p.Results.Where(r => r.Mark5 == 2).ToList() })
    .Where(pm => pm.Mark5_2.Count == 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pm => pm.Mark5_2[0].Mark5 = 3);
```